# Linear regression: why do unnecessary variables increase variance of regression estimates

Tags: statistics, regression

In the setting of multiple linear regression where $Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1*X_{i1} + ... \beta_p*X_{ip} + \epsilon_i$ and $\epsilon_i \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$ and $Cov(\epsilon_i, \epsilon_j) = 0$. I've been told that unnecessary covariates will increase the variance of the regression coefficients i.e increase $Var(\hat{\beta}) = \sigma^2(X'X)^{-1}$, as they waste degrees of freedom without contributing to the regression sum of squares $B'X'Y - n\bar{Y}^2$. Why is this? Can someone elaborate on this?

Also, $Var(\hat{Y})$ will also increase as number of covariates goes up. Why is this?